# How to manage files while there are Jade and Stylus to compile?

Tags: bash, node.js, coffeescript, pug

I usually white pages in Jade, Stylus and CoffeeScript, so I use a shell script to watch them all and compile. And use a shell script with `pkill -f` to kill them after coding.

But there's problems:

- if I call this script from another directory, it fails
- if I forget to run the second script, it will just run,

http://gitcafe.com/jiyinyiyong/weibo-list/blob/master/watch/watch.sh#code

```
jade -O ../page/ --pretty -w ../src/index.jade &
jade -O ../page/ --pretty -w ../src/login.jade &
coffee -o ../page/ -wbc ../src/handle.coffee &
coffee -o ../page/ -wbc ../src/config.coffee &
stylus -o ../page/ -w ../src/page.styl &
doodle ../page/ ../server.coffee &
node-dev ../server.coffee &
```

Is there a better solution to manage these files?

Comment: Dunno if this is the best method, but I use `Cakefile` to automate these... My [Cakefile](https://github.com/GotEmB/Download-To-Dropbox/blob/master/Cakefile). It's the same one I use in all my projects.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the code which handle stderr and stdout.. so I chose Bash first. thx for the examples. There's a problem, how to  kill the process(better to kill at a keyboard event) if I add `-w` option to `stylus` command?

Comment: You can always end a process by `Ctrl + C`. That'll kill the cake process as well as all its child processes. If this really did help you, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: I understand now. `cake` file works on my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Cakefile` to automate such tasks.

My [`Cakefile`](https://github.com/GotEmB/Download-To-Dropbox/blob/master/Cakefile). I use the same one for all my projects.

For more info, see [`cake.coffee`](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/cake.html).